# How does FitGirl achieve such a high compression ratio?

Tags: compression

I noticed that FitGirl can compress a 50 GB folder into a 30 GB one. How does she do it ? what is this tool or algorithm called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their [FAQ page](https://fitgirl-repacks.site/faq):

> Q: How do you compress games? With what tools?
>
> A: I use mostly FreeArc for compression and Inno Setup as an installer. Some games require other compressors, but in 99.9% of cases it’s FreeArc.